# Lock user screen with custom full screen image and prevent unlock using ssh

Tags: ssh, lock-screen

I want to connect to a computer using ssh, lock the computer's screen by displaying a full screen custom text/image and prevent user from doing anything until I unlock the screen again using ssh.
How is this possible?

For example let's say I am the teacher of a class and I want to lock all of my students screens until I let them to use their computers.